# Cannot reassociate accounts after clearing associations

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-accounts, association

I associated my accounts on stackoverflow, serverfault, superuser and meta.

I associated some of them from stackoverflow and some of them from superuser.

Afterwards I tried clearing the associations and assigning the associations again.

I now get

```
Can't Associate This Account

[...] cannot associate your [...] account:

because it is already associated.
```

Whenever I try associating any other combination than stackoverflow-serverfault.

My accounts are:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/5542
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5542
- https://superuser.com/users/4601
- https://serverfault.com/users/11402

This might be a reoccurence of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5887/none-of-the-other-sites-can-associate-my-superuser-account-because-it-is-already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

was a bug deployed last night, should be fixed now -- try again!